# Is it possible to disable the source/destination check from the Amazon SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating a VPC in Amazon's cloud, but I can't figure out how to disable the source/dest check on my NAT instance from the AWS SDK. Specifically, I am using ruby and the docs show a call that will return a boolean indicating if it is on or not: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Instance.html#source_dest_check-instance_method

I don't see anywhere that I can actually set it from the AWS SDK. I can do it through the console or through the command line tools, but it looks like they might have left this out of the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it hasn't been left out from the API. You can use this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Client.html#modify_instance_attribute-instance_method

or this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Client.html#modify_network_interface_attribute-instance_method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, this case is more simple than that. The attribute on the Instance class is writable. I saw the '?' on the end and assumed read-only, but there are actually two attributes, one of which has no '?' and is writable.

Comment: That's great, make sure you push the update through the AWS API once you update the attribute as I believe the update may just be local.

Comment: For those in google land, @despotes's idea works: `@ec2.instances["i-xxxxxx"].source_dest_check = false` works and sets it remotely right then. No need to call modify_instance_attribute.